# Number of digits in a number with lisp using cond

Tags: lisp

So, I know that there is a solution using the if statement which is the following

```
    (defun numdigits (n)
      (if (< -10 n 10)
         1
         (1+ (numdigits (truncate n 10)))))
```

But I'm trying to deepen my knowledge and to understand to go for transforming if statements to the cond statement. SO I tried it out using the cond statement, but I  receive an error, and quite honestly, I don't know why.

Here's what I did:

```
    (defun nbDigits (digit)
     (cond 
          ((> 0 (- digit 10)) 1)
          (t (1 + (nbDigits (truncate digit 10))))
      )
     )
```

The logic I'm having is:
If 0 is greater than x-10, return 1 ( as this means the number is smaller than 10). Else, return 1 + nbDigits(the quotient of the digit when it's divided by 10), which should go until it reaches the base case.

I'm getting the error:
Illegal argument in functor position: 1 in (1 + (NBDIGITS (TRUNCATE DIGIT 10))).
But I don't understand how to go about this error.. Did I do a wrong call?
Thanks.

Comment: do you have a function nbDigits?

Comment: do you have a function called 1 ?

Comment: Im trying to use recursion? So I'm defining the function nbDigits..

Comment: Are you saying 1 is considered a function in this case..? if so.. How would I go about fixing that..?

Comment: how about the function 1 ?

Comment: And if so, why is it the case? that its considered as a function?

Comment: what is the syntax for function calls in Lisp?

Comment: (function argument)?

Comment: Okay, I think I solved my function calling problem, it seems I know have a misunderstanding with the recursion as no matter what number I input, I always seem to get 1 as an answer (returning the base case number, does not add the 1's from the recursion calls). Do you think you can help? @Rainer Joswig

Comment: @R.DM That's correct, so `(1 + (nbDigits ...))` means to call `1` as a function, with `+` and `(nbDigits ...)` as the two arguments. Notice the difference between `(1+ ...)` and `(1 + ...)`. The first calls the function named `1+`, the second calls the function named `1`.

Comment: Ohhhhh! I didn't think it spaces made a difference.. I'll try something out, thanks!

Comment: Spaces separate the function name from the function arguments, and arguments from each other.

Comment: @Barmar Yes! thank you very much! I tried at first thinking about what Rainer said, and I did (t 1 + (nbDigits(truncate digit 10))), but that returned always 1 from the base case. Would you happen to know why recursion didn't backtrack and add all the 1's? Thanks again!

Comment: You still don't have the function name immediately after the `(`. The function you want to call is `+`, so you need something that looks like `(+ 1 ...)`

Comment: Oh right! I feel silly now. Thanks again!

Comment: You probably also want to do some testing. `-1` has 1 digit, `-10` has two digits, just as `1` has 1 and `10` has two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple space between `1` and `+` is changing the function `1+` into two elements. Remove that space and you are done.

Incidentally, simplify your math by writing `(< digit 10)` instead of `(> 0 (- digit 10))`

In the end it should look like this:

```
(defun nbDigits (digit)
     (cond 
          ((< digit 10) 1)
          (t (1+ (nbDigits (truncate digit 10))))
      )
     )
```

Comment: Well... The original returns correct values for all integers, the second only for positive integers (both in your case and in OP's case).

Comment: True, but don't forget that R.DM's intentions are just to gain experience with cond. In reality one would never think of implementing this function like this. I would do either (length (format nil "~d" (abs n))) or (1+ (truncate (log (abs n) 10)))

Comment: Yep, I am just wary of "I am trying to rewrite this function with cond" resulting in a different function.